# I want to show another google maps fragment v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm developing android tablet project. There is dualpane layout. In the left side there is leftscrollfrg fragment, it's also execute right side, mainmapfragment, it opens the map. In the left side, i click createproject button and when i click the button it hides the mainmapfragment and adds another fragment which is viewpager fragment. In the first page there is CreateProjectFrg1 fragment and inside there is button which adds another map fragment (CreateProjectMapFrg).

The problem is when the second map opened, the first one is showed like frozen. But i can see the new opened map because the old one padded from left and right. And also when i turn off the screen and back on, the old one map which frozen is gone.

How can i solve this problem?

Note: In the hierarchy view, i cannot see the frozen map.

[image: Frozen Map]

```
public class LeftScrollFrg extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_left_behind, container, false);

            frg_map = (MainMapFragment) getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (frg_map == null) {

                    frg_map = new MainMapFragment();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();

                    ft.replace(R.id.above_framelayout, frg_map, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    ft.addToBackStack(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    ft.commit();
            }

            imgbtn_createproject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    hideMainMapFrg();

                    openCreateProjectFrg();
                }
            });

            imgbtn_map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    hideCreateProjectFrg();

                    openMapFrg();

                }
            });
            return vw;
    }

        private void hideMainMapFrg() {

            fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            frg_map = (MainMapFragment) fm
                    .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

            if (fm != null) {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                if (frg_map != null) {
                    if (frg_map.isVisible()) {
                        ft.hide(frg_map);
                    }
                }
            }
            ft.commit();

        }

        private void openMapFrg() {
            fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            frg_map = (MainMapFragment) fm
                    .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

            if (fm != null) {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();


                if (frg_createproject != null) {
                    if (frg_createproject.isVisible()) {
                        ft.hide(frg_createproject);
                    }
                }

                if (frg_map == null) {
                    frg_map = new MainMapFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.above_framelayout, frg_map, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                } else {
                    if (frg_map.isHidden()) {
                        ft.show(frg_map);
                    }
                }
                ft.addToBackStack(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.commit();
            }

        }
    }

    public class MainMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements
            LocationListener, LocationSource, OnInfoWindowClickListener,
            OnMapClickListener {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_mainproject, container, false);


            return view;
            }


    }

    //frg_mainproject.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/rightpanel_margin" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
            />
    </RelativeLayout>





    public class CreateProjectFrg1 extends Fragment{
            @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_createproject1, container,
                    false);

            imgvw_createprojectmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    openCreateMap();
                }
            });

                    return vw;
            }

                private void openCreateMap() {
            fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            frg_map = (CreateProjectMapFrg) fm
                    .findFragmentByTag(CREATEPROJECTMAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);



            if (fm != null) {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                if (frg_map == null) {

                    frg_map = new CreateProjectMapFrg();
                    ft.add(R.id.above_framelayout, frg_map, CREATEPROJECTMAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                }
                ft.addToBackStack(CREATEPROJECTMAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.commit();


            }

        }


    }







    public class CreateProjectMapFrg extends SupportMapFragment implements
            OnMapClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            if (view != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(view);
            }

            try {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_createprojectmap, container,
                        false);
            } catch (InflateException e) {

            }
            setViewsResource(view);
            setUpMapIfNeeded();

            return view;
        }

            private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

            if (mMap == null) {

                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                                R.id.frg_createproject_map)).getMap();

                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    //frg_createprojectmap.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frg_createproject_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

**Updated code**

Answer (score 0):

This is https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027

As a workaround you can explicitely remove / replace the `MapFragment` from the fragment manager instead of just hiding it. If you don't want to remove the fragment as a whole, you can also implement your own Fragment that just uses `MapView` and detaches that just before the fragment is hidden (might need some more custom code).